# How to add 2 different times in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to convert from GMT to UTC time and would like to add the 2 different times.

Here is the code that I have currently :

```
Dim CurDate, Correction, UTCTime As Date
CurDate = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
UTCTime = DateAdd("h", 4.5, CurDate)
```

However it is adding only the integer part of the hours i.e., 4 and not 4.5

Any idea, how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
UTCTime = DateAdd("n", 4.5 * 60, CurDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, the integer part of a date is days, so adding 4.5 hours would be adding 4.5/24

```
UTCTime = CurDate + 4.5 / 24
```